# Java Hash Table Issue with Object Reference

Tags: java, c, oop, hashmap, hashtable

I have a Hash Table like,

```
HashTable ht = { (1, 1), (2, 1), (3, 1) }
```

Now, I implement it like, Integer foo = Integer(1) and declare hash table like,

```
HashTable ht = { (foo, foo), (2, foo), (3, foo) }
```

Now, as per I understood from [this](http://www.kdgregory.com/index.php?page=java.refobj), **it will reduce heap space used by JVM. Is this correct ?** Another point is that, in C, I usually use structure like,

```
HashTable ht = { (1, mem), (2, mem), (3, mem) } 
{ where mem is memory location (say 10) of 1 }
```

And then use the location to access the value. Now, if mem value is less than Int (say Byte), I can save space. However, I don't understand how to implement this in Java. **Or is there any other way to reduce space of the hash table ? (means by reducing repeatedly storing same object in Java's way).**

Comment: If you are worried about space, why are you using a hash table instead of a tree?

Comment: @erickson, because of Performance.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] to illustrate your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most space-efficient way with `Integer`s is to use `Integer.valueOf()`, which uses the flyweight design pattern to reduce the memory usage for small values. Values between -128 and (usually) 127 need no additional memory.

Comment: Thanks. That will help. However, what I really want is little bit different means not to waste more space for same object.